# Exceptions in PHP - uncaught

Tags: php, exception

I use to writing my own exceptions in php, its pretty easy ectually. all you have do is something like:

```
class Test extends Exception{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0){
    }
}
```

the problem I keep getting is that when ever I do something like:

```
throw new Test('bla');
```

I get:

```
uncaught exception with message bla.
```

why?

Comment: You don't catch your exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't catch it, maybe?  :p

```
try {
  throw new Test('bla');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  // caught it
}
```

Please [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for proper Exception usage

Comment: why would I have to try and throw my own exception?

Comment: Because they're exceptions. That's how they work.

Comment: I assumed it was try and open a file, catch any exception. not try and throw an error

Comment: The try block handles any code which *may* throw an exception. The catch block handles any exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: I just feel that with this approach there will be a lot of try catches.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use one try/catch block to handle lots of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception without any `catch` block higher in the call stack, the exception will go uncaugth, thus the error message you get. Maybe you should read more on [how exceptions work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to really grok the concept.