# Writing functions that deal with exceptions

Tags: php, exception

[Building upon a question I already asked regarding exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945789/exceptions-in-php-uncaught#14945828), I fear that I might be writing php functions wrong then, or abusing the use of exceptions. The reason I say this, is because if custom exceptions are to be caught using try/catch blocks then the following function:

```
public function get_specific_page($page) {
    if (!is_array( $this->_page )){
        throw new AisisCore_Template_TemplateException( "<div class='error'>Trying to get a property from a non array.</div>" );
    }

    return $this->_page[$page];
}
```

Would then be called such as:

```
try{
    get_specific_page($page);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have many functions that are written like this, either checking to see if a file exists, throwing an error. Checking to see if a value is set in an array, throwing an error and my issue is that the file which deals with these function calls may become over loaded with try catch.....

So my question is, how would I better write functions like this so that I don't have php files over loaded with try catch statements, yet still be able to have y own custom functions.

Is it as obvious as writing the try catch inside the function it's self?

The reason I ask, if because I am use to working with fameworks and in companies where we write our functions as you see above. How ver I have worked with code bases that have tons of these functions and I dont see half the files that are useing them doing a bunch of try catches...

**Update:**

I was looking through zend source to better understand exceptions and came across this:

```
public function setMessage($messageString, $messageKey = null)
    {
        if ($messageKey === null) {
            $keys = array_keys($this->_messageTemplates);
            foreach($keys as $key) {
                $this->setMessage($messageString, $key);
            }
            return $this;
        }

        if (!isset($this->_messageTemplates[$messageKey])) {
            require_once 'Zend/Validate/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Validate_Exception("No message template exists for key '$messageKey'");
        }

        $this->_messageTemplates[$messageKey] = $messageString;
        return $this;
    }
```

You can see how they throw a new exception message near the bottom, this function is not called by doing:

```
try{}catch(){}
```

yet when it throws an exception, there is no issue with "uncaught exception with message"

Comment: Zend has its own exception handlers, some of them the handler catches itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, your approach is correct in general. However, a few notes:

1. You should refrain from using HTML formatting in exception messages. Generally, you don't know how the exception that you throw will be handled. For example, an exception handler could just write the message to a log file (you don't want HTML formatting then), present it to the user in a special error view (in which case the view itself should contain the HTML formatting), or simply ignore it (no need for formatting then, anyway).
2. Catch only exceptions that you can handle. If you know that your function throws an `AisisCore_Template_TemplateException`, you should just catch that exception and let all other exceptions bubble up to an exception handler that *can* handle them. You can use `set_exception_handler` to define such an exception handler that catches all uncaught exceptions by default (this is probably the case in your example from Zend Framework). Plainly put: **Only catch exceptions in places where you know how to handle them**.
3. Only use exceptions as what the name implies: to handle (unexpected) exceptions in your control flow. Using exceptions to control the regular flow of your program is possible, but generally considered bad design (just as a side note, your code samples look alright).

For the sake of completeness, some alternatives to using exceptions:

1. Use return codes instead of exceptions. This is old-school C-style. The advantage is that you don't need to wrap statements with try/catch-statements. However, you have to check the return values of each procedure, which is easy to forget. When using exceptions on the other hand, you reduce the risk of unexpected errors, since uncaught exceptions produce a fatal error per default.
2. Use PHP errors. See the [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) function for this. Custom errors are however nearly impossible to catch in PHP (except by using [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), which only works at global level).

Comment: i agree with helmbert. Especially on the part that says you need to add return codes. I strongly feel you should use return codes as much as possible and only throw Exceptions when stuff goes so wrong you have to break the original code block and move to the exception handler. In a lot of cases the return code will allow the calling function/program to take different actions.

Comment: Well, the point that I actually tried to make was that in my opinion, exceptions are more elegant and more safe to use than return codes, but this issue obviously is subject to individual taste... ;)