# Creating a error handler class in php

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I recently have been asking question on exceptions and handling exceptions and such, [which as recently best explained to me in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946338/writing-functions-that-deal-with-exceptions#comment20978551_14946338) My question now is how would I use the

```
set_exception_handler();
```

in a class to set up a error handling class in php, that when ever an error is thrown is handled by this class. As the definition states:

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
class Test{
    public function __construct(){
        set_exception_handler('exception');
    }

    public function exception($exception){
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But then the problem is that if the user is setting up the application or using any API from the application they have to do a whole: `new Test();`

So how could I write an exception handler class that is:

1. Automatically called when an exception is thrown to deal with the "uncaught" exception.
2. Done in an OOP way that is extendible.

The way I have shown is the only way I can think to do it.

Comment: This really should be in official PHP help, marked as `the best practices`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your class to work, the line inside your contructor should be:

```
// if you want a normal method        
set_exception_handler(array($this, 'exception'));

// if you want a static method (add "static" to your handler method
set_exception_handler(array('Test', 'exception'));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning, in general, when you want to pass a function name to something and the function is actually an object method, you use the syntax shown here.  That is to say, this solution works for other PHP methods expecting a function name.

Comment: I saw my error a head of time, my concern is that if the user is setting up the application this is yet another class they have to call as a "new" object.

Comment: I know this is for long time ago but it is better to use `static::class` instead of just the name of the class for the static methods. By using that you can support namespacing. `set_exception_handler(array(static::class, 'exception'));`

Answer (score 9):

Everybody thinks that using set_exception_handler would catch all the error in the PHP but it is not true as some errors are not handled by the set_exception_handler the proper way to handle all types of errors have to be done as:

```
 //Setting for the PHP Error Handler
 set_error_handler( call_back function or class );

 //Setting for the PHP Exceptions Error Handler
 set_exception_handler(call_back function or class);

 //Setting for the PHP Fatal Error
 register_shutdown_function(call_back function or class);
```

By setting these three setting you can catch all the errors of PHP.